# Why is $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ also true when $x=-1$, making it $i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

**A :** If: $$\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$$ 
only when $x,y>0$,

**B :** Then why **can** I do this:

$$\sqrt{-4}=\sqrt{4\times-1}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{-1}=2i$$

which violates **A** since $y<0$

**C :** But why can I **not** do this?

$$\sqrt{4}=\sqrt{-1\times-1\times4}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{4}=i\cdot i\cdot2=-2$$

Which follows the same reasoning as **B**.

Comment: Your first statement $A$ is wrong..$\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$ holds iff at least one of $x$ and $y$ is positive.

Comment: Because the condition $x,y>0$ doesn't mean that it can NEVER be true if $y<0$, it just means that there's no reason the expect it to be true. So you B case is just an example that 'just happens' to work. remember 'false$\Rightarrow$ true' holds.

Comment: $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ is also for $x>0,y<0$ or $x<0,y>0$

Comment: @OP Source for statement A?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ if and only if $-\pi < \arg x + \arg y \le \pi$, where $\sqrt x$ denotes the principal square root and $\arg x$ denotes the principal argument. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402936/when-does-sqrtwz-sqrtw-sqrtz) for details.

If $x$ and $y$ are positive numbers, then $\arg x + \arg y = 0 + 0 = 0$, so the identity holds.

In your case **B**, $\arg(4) + \arg(-1) = 0 + \pi = \pi$, so the identity still holds.

In your case **C**, $\arg(-1) + \arg(-1) = \pi + \pi = 2\pi$, so the identity fails.