# What is wrong with this proof? -3 = 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, fractions, absolute-value, fake-proofs

What is wrong with this proof?

$-3 = \sqrt[3]{-27} = {(-27)}^{\frac 13} = {(-27)}^{\frac 26} = \sqrt[6]{{(-27)}^2} = \sqrt[6]{{27}^2} = {(27)}^{\frac 26} = {(27)}^{\frac 13} = \sqrt[3]{27} = 3$

This is obviously false since $-3 \neq 3$.

But still I can't figure out which equation is the wrong one and why that is.

Thanks in advance for anyone who will help.

Comment: The third equality is completely wrong...

Comment: $(-27)^{1/3} = (-27)^{2/6} \neq ((-27)^2)^{1/6}$

Comment: @yanko I know it's wrong. I asked this question to understand why.

Comment: It's obviously wrong because you reach a contradiction.. what made you think that would be true in the first place?

Comment: You can also check some other related posts, such as: [Which step in this process allows me to erroneously conclude that $i = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84436),  [Which step in this process allows me to erroneously conclude that $i = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84436), [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49169) and [When does $\sqrt{a b} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2047349)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in comments, the $(-27)^{2/6} \neq ((-27)^2)^{1/6}$, because $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ does not generally hold for $a<0$.

You can find more related info in @mrf's answer here: [Is $(-1)^{ab} = (-1)^{ba}$ true? => $(-1)^{ab} = ((-1)^a )^b$ is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576480/is-1ab-1ba-true-1ab-1a-b-is-true?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3):

The mistake here:

$$(-27)^{\frac{2}{6}}=(-27)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$
It's wrong because
$$(-27)^{\frac{2}{6}}=|-27|^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$
Also if we write $a^{\frac{1}{3}}$ then it's better to think that $a>0$.

Answer (score -1):

you could aswell prove this:

$-1 = \sqrt {(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$

Clearly the first equality is wrong (and your's third equality is wrong for similar reason).