# How can I simplify $\sqrt{50y^8}$ to $5y^4\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question is in the title. My textbook has given me the question and solution but nothing in between. For this question I do not even know where to start.

In this chapter I've been learning about radicals, including the product and quotient rule, along with how to add and subtract radicals, rationalizing denominators and rational exponents.

Yet, for this particular question I'm struggling to even get started and understand what my first step would be?

I tried expressing the base as a exponent as opposed to a radical $50y^{2/8}$ to see if that would lead me down a path but it did not.

I find this question tricky because I am not sure which of the things I've been reading about in this chapter to apply here with a goal of simplifying the expression to $5y^4\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\sqrt{50y^8}$ in the title?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a square in the second expression. $(5y^4\sqrt{2})^2$ gives you $25y^8\cdot 2$

Comment: Anyway, it looks like all you're missing the fact that for any two real numbers $a,b$ one has $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$. So for instance since $50=25*2$ we have $\sqrt{50} = \sqrt{25}\sqrt{2} = 5\cdot \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, yes sorry and I've updated the title now too.

Comment: Check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047349/when-does-sqrta-b-sqrta-sqrtb

Comment: Thanks @Yanko! I think I can take it from there following your feedback and comment. Should I delete?

Comment: Someone answered so I'll accept when the timer comes off, thanks for your help here

Comment: @DougFir You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that:

$$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$$
(when $a,b>0$)

Particularly useful here is:

$$\sqrt{a^2b}=a\sqrt b$$